# Git staging branch is n commits behind master after pull request

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

For this project, the base branch is master branch and there is a staging branch that is branched off master.

All the issue branches are branched off staging and merged to staging.
Then ultimately staging branch will be merged to master.

I think I screwed up at some point and now when I merge staging to master, after pull request is accepted, the staging branch is commits behind master even though the code content is the exactly the same in staging and master.

How should I fix this?
If I git rebase origin/master then merge to master again, would it solve this problem?

Comment: Without seeing the actual situation, it's hard to tell.